# cp not updating when using hasMany(..).value() instead of get(..)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I created a jsbin: https://ember-twiddle.com/52edd8462fa6e3cf1a147a2a047c9207?openFiles=models.post.js%2C

*Issue:* cp `characters` on `post` does not get updated when property `content` changes on `comment`.

*'Fix':* the change does happen when using `this.get('comments')` instead of `this.hasMany('comments').value()`.

`get` notifies observers that it should look for changes on the property because it is being used, while `hasMany` does not seem to have this functionality..

Is this on purpose or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

you are not iterating over `model.comments.` thats why you are facing problem.
try to use following code in template. its working

```
{{#each model.comments as |comment|}}
    <div>
    content: {{input value=comment.content}}
  </div>

  <div>
    characters: {{comment.characters}}
    </div>

  <br /><br />
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Please dont forget to accept my answer. its better than simple thanks :)

Comment: your example works because it's using model.get('comments') internally which works as I explained. My example explicitly calls `comments` via `.hasMany` as defined on controller level.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `hasMany().value()` will return the current value of the model and `null` if there is no value yet (not yet retrieved from the backend). It can be used to check if the model is already loaded or not, it will not trigger a load to the server. This is intended behaviour, to just get the content without triggering a load.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by modifying the private api.

The solution is available via following `ember-addon`: https://github.com/dylanmensaert/ember-data-peek-relationship